# Bad behavior with printf and multiple strings

Tags: c++, printf, inet

When I use printf/printf_s with two strings, I get the same output for both %s vars.

```
IN_ADDR oldIP;
oldIP.S_un.S_addr = iptable[j]->ipAddress;
IN_ADDR newIP;
newIP.S_un.S_addr = adapterTbl->table[i].dwAddr;
printf_s("index %d old: %s new: %s", 
          adapterTbl->table[i].dwIndex, inet_ntoa(oldIP),
           inet_ntoa(newIP));
```

Output is:

```
index 11 old: 192.168.1.1 new: 192.168.1.1
```

Now, I have checked that the values of oldip and newip are different by breaking before the print statement, and I have also tried to make the following function and use it in the print statement (instead of inet_ntoa):

```
char *convertIP (DWORD ip)  
{  
    IN_ADDR *addr = new IN_ADDR;
    memset(addr, 0, sizeof(IN_ADDR));
    addr->S_un.S_addr = (u_long) ip;
    return inet_ntoa(*addr);
}
```

The output with this was:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
index 11 old: 192.168.1.1 new: 192.168.1.1
```

Why am I seeing this behavior, and how can I fix it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` retuns:

> a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls overwrite

(This is from the Linux manpage.)

You can't use it twice in a function, only the output of the second call will be visible (and you don't know which one of the two calls is the second - order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified).

Do two separate `printf`s, or copy the output of `inet_ntoa` to local buffers and output those.

From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/inet_addr.html):

> The return value of *inet_ntoa*() may point to static data that may be overwritten by subsequent calls to *inet_ntoa*().

So this behavior is probably not limited to Linux, and you can't rely on it *not* overwriting a static buffer.

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons that Mat described, you must use the result of one call to `inet_ntoa` before performing the next call.

Here is one easy way to do that:

```
IN_ADDR oldIP;
oldIP.S_un.S_addr = iptable[j]->ipAddress;
IN_ADDR newIP;
newIP.S_un.S_addr = adapterTbl->table[i].dwAddr;
std::string s_old(inet_ntoa(oldIP));
std::string s_new(inet_ntoa(newIP));
printf_s("index %d old: %s new: %s", 
      adapterTbl->table[i].dwIndex, s_old.c_str(),
       s_new.c_str());
```

Note that the `string` constructor makes a copy of the passed-in C string. Thus, when `inet_ntoa` is invoked again, it is free to overwrite its previously-stored value.